# WireGuard MacOS Error - Catalina 10.15.5

Tags: vpn, wireguard

I am trying to connect to WireGuard VPN, downloaded from App Store on MacOS. I am having a .config file that looks like this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ----value-----
Address = ----value-----
DNS =  ----value-----
MTU = ----value-----
[Peer]
PublicKey = ----value-----
PresharedKey = ----value-----
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
Endpoint = ----value-----
```

When I use the Import tunnel from the config file, it gives me an error:

```
Unable to create tunnel; Reading or writing the configuration failed.
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

DNS and MTU are not valid options. You probably meant to set these options in a different file. These are general network settings and not wireguard specific. You can refer to the documentation for valid wireguard options, their effects, and how to format them.

There are also examples showing how to format the keys and ips in the docs as well, just in case you have a key or ip formatting error.

https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/wireguard-tools/wg.8.en.html#CONFIGURATION_FILE_FORMAT

Answer (score 0):

see this tutorial about [Wireguard VPN on mac](https://bestproxy.net/articles/wireguard-vpn-macos-how-to-setup-it)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).